# How to set default text in the combobox using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am binding a combobox in the WPF using MVVM pattern. I am able to bind a list of string with the combobox but I don't know how to set a default value in the combobox.
Well I have a list of names which has "A","B","C" and "D". Now I want that by default "A" should come as default value.

Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:NameViewModel></ViewModel:NameViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public class NameViewModel
{
   private IList<string> _nameList = new List<string>();
   public IList<string> Names { get; set; }
   public NameViewModel()
   {
       Names = GetAllNames();
   }

   private IList<string> GetAllNames()
   {
       IList<string> names = new List<string>();
       names.Add("A");
       names.Add("B");
       names.Add("C");
       names.Add("D");
       return names;
   }
}
```

Comment: Set SelectedItem via another view model property?

Comment: Yes Alan now i got it,,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to use ListItem. ListItem has Selected property

Comment: yes,but combobox in WPF is also having SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the easiest way to achieve this is bind the selected item as well...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:NameViewModel></ViewModel:NameViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox 
           Height="23" 
           Width="120" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}"
           />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public class NameViewModel
{
   private IList<string> _nameList = new List<string>();
   public IList<string> Names { get; set; }
   public string SelectedName { get; set; }
   public NameViewModel()
   {
       Names = GetAllNames();
       SelectedName = "A";
   }

   private IList<string> GetAllNames()
   {
       IList<string> names = new List<string>();
       names.Add("A");
       names.Add("B");
       names.Add("C");
       names.Add("D");
       return names;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to go. It should be mentioned though, if it isn't obvious, that if you're going to use the "SelectedItem" property of the ComboBox, whatever you're binding to MUST be an item in the ItemsSource collection, otherwise nothing will show by default.

Comment: @Ryan, yes its pretty obvious that selected item would only work if that particular item must be an item in the ItemsSource collection.