# Default Value in a Combobox using ModelViewViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox

I want to set a default value in this ComboBox. The ItemsSource contains two elements. I want that the second element is the default when I open the window that contains my combobox. Here's the code.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Name="_cmbServiceType" Visibility="Visible" 
                              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FL_TYPE, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ClientList}"
                              SelectedValuePath="FL_TYPE"
                              DisplayMemberPath="ID_TYPE"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<GenericEnumType<string>> _clientList = null;
    public ObservableCollection<GenericEnumType<string>> ClientList
    {
       get
         {
                Master.Controller.Execute(delegate(IResult result)
                {
                    _clientList = new ObservableCollection<GenericEnumType<string>>() 
                        { 
                            new GenericEnumType<string>(SAPClient.WEBSERVICE_URL_500.ToString(), CappTranslate.Translate.EBOM),
                            new GenericEnumType<string>(SAPClient.WEBSERVICE_URL_400.ToString(), CappTranslate.Translate.PBOM),
                        };
                    return true;
                });

                return _clientList;
            }
        }

private GenericEnumType<string> _selectedItem = null;
public GenericEnumType<string> SelectedItem
{
     get { return _selectedItem; }
     set
         {
          _selectedItem = value;

          if (_selectedItem.FL_TYPE == SAPClient.WEBSERVICE_URL_500.ToString())
                       _selectedBomUsage = null;

          OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
          OnPropertyChanged(() => CanClose);
          OnPropertyChanged(() => IsComboUsageEnabled);
          OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedBomUsage);
         }
            }
```

I tried to set in My Constructor:

```
SelectedItem = ClientList[1];
```

But it doesn't work.

Some suggestions??

Comment: why don't you give a try on this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691452/how-to-set-default-text-in-the-combobox-using-mvvm

Comment: Solved! I need to set also the SelectedIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, you should not set both, SelectedValue AND SelectedItem.

Try to just set the SelectedItem.

Comment: It doesn't work. But I think it's a UI problem because I have a button that permit to confirm the selection if the SelectedItem is not null. So The SelectedItem is correctly set but I can't see it

Comment: Solved! I need to set also the SelectedIndex